# Why is there an option to change the output path for DCP/BPL files if it doesn't work?

Tags: delphi

We have lots of 3rd party libraries. Their code was all compiled into the `.dpr` directly. Now my team wants to switch two libraries, but they want to put all binaries into the repo so when they switch between branches they don't need to recompile the libraries.

So, I brought back all the deleted `.dpk` files and changed the settings of those files to output the `.dcu`, `.bpl` and `.dcp` to a "local" folder so we can commit them.

However, if Package2 depends on Package1, then the IDE needs to find `Package1.dcp` in `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Dcp`.

I tried to provide the path to the "local" folder where the `.bpl`/`.dcp` is, via "IDE Options -> Library path", but Delphi will not find it. When I try to install Package2 I get an error:

> Can't load package Package1.bpl. The specified module could not be found.

So, why would Delphi let you change the output path for `.dcp`/`.bpl` if it cannot take those files from there?

---

Personal note: I am strongly against committing the binaries. I would definitively stay with a "classic" configuration for those `.dpk`s. But since the general decision was to do it this way, I have to make it work.

Comment: You can try to add the local bpl folder to the IDE environment variable PATH.

Comment: @UweRaabe - Thanks. Sounds good. I will have to see which is the limit for that path (I know there is a limit) because we have many of those "local" folders.

Comment: Use a separate environment variable for your folders and add that variable to the PATH variable.

Comment: Check the project settings of your `Package2`. It is possible that you have different paths specified in the project options themselves. They always override the default IDE settings.

Comment: Example use case for this option: You want to test whether your changes in the source code compile but you might not want to overwrite the package that is currently loaded into the IDE. (But I must admint that I have never actually used that option myself.)

Comment: @UweRaabe - in D11 I put the hardcoded path to the folder where I output my DCP into "Tools ->Options->System Env Variables ->User system overrides -> Path" but the IDE still complains that it won't find the DCP. As usual the help doesn't tell much about what to do in such case: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Delphi_Compiled_Package_File_(*.dcp)

Comment: As usual, the help doesn't tell much about what to do in such case: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Delphi_Compiled_Package_File_(*.dcp)

Comment: PATH experiment: In D11 I put the hard coded (no $(Platform and stuff) substitutes) path to the folder where I output my DCP into "Tools ->Options->System Env Variables ->User system overrides -> Path" but the IDE still complains that it won't find the DCP.

Comment: Only bpl files are searched by the PATH variable. For DCP you have to add the specific folder to the IDE library path or project search path. Mind that these entries are platform specific.

Comment: I figured out that I cannot use $(Something) in the Env Paths. Once I switched to hard-coded paths, it worked... BUT... only until I restart the IDE. After restart, the IDE complains again that it cannot find the BPL ("Do you want to attempt to load this package next time a project is loaded? Yes/No"). Installing the package manually works... until the next IDE restart.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by faking the presence of the BPL files in the
".....\Embarcadero\Studio\xx.0\BPL" folder via symbolic links.